# Random Sitecore Logout Issues

Tags: sitecore-client, login, user-profile

**Running Sitecore version 8.1**

Hello, I've been trying to figure out this issue for a while now and was curious to see if anyone has experienced something similar.

**Issue:** `Content publishers` get kicked out of `Sitecore` while actively working in both the `content editor` and `experience editor`. Happens to both standard accounts and `admin accounts`. The time between logouts seems to be completely random and will happen multiple times a day. It also happens in multiple browsers (Chrome, Edge, and Firefox). When they log back in, they have to re-adjust the size of the menus as if they had cleared their browser cache. All unsaved work is gone.

I can't see if the browser prints any errors as the page gets refreshed back to the login page automatically.

I ran Wireshark while a user was in Sitecore and saw `TCP RST` (Reset Packets) from our Sitecore Server when the user got kicked out. Does not seem to happen when you log out normally.

**Steps I've taken:**

- Flushed DNS and cleaned hosts file
- Refreshed chrome
- Fresh install of chrome
- Switched browsers
- Changed IP from static to dynamic
- Changed computer name
- Deleted and recreated windows 10 user profile
- Moved them outside the corporate network
- Completely new install of windows 10

All of these have failed to fix the issue. However, there were two instances where the logouts stopped for a period of time.

1. A combination of a new user profile, dynamic IP, different computer name
2. Fresh install of Windows 10.

The fresh install seemed to be the fix as it was working for several weeks. The issue has since returned, and I restored the machine to a previous point. No changes were made to the system, nor were any updates installed. And even though the restore point is less than 24 hours old, the registry changes are just too many to sift through.

**Other Notes:**
Not sure where, but I ran across `Microsoft BITS` (Background Intelligent Transfer Service) as a potential culprit, so I ran these commands but found nothing. (this was before fresh windows install)

- Ran sfc/scannow  -> found nothing
- Ran dism/Online/Cleanup-image/Scanhealth -> found nothing
- Ran dism/Online/Cleanup-image/Restorehealth  anyway
- Ran diagnostic tool for Windows BITS  -> found nothing

Comment: What we really need, is the Sitecore logfiles. All of the above seems to indicate steps you have taken _on the clients_ but none of that would explain why Sitecore - server side - would restart.  Likely the last entries of a Sitecore log before a restart would hold a clue. Could also simply because the server is racking up loads of exceptions in the background which will ultimately make IIS restart the AppPool.

Comment: Is there any custom code that was designed to run periodically and log out users?

Comment: Didn't realize there was a log. I'll work on gathering more info when we experience another random logout.

The only thing I see so far is this:

9908 13:54:02 INFO  AUDIT (sitecore\Anonymous): Logout

I don't believe there was any custom code written for logouts nor was anything adjusted.

Comment: Did you check the value of Authentication.ClientSessionTimeout setting? Also is the number of allowed concurrent users being reached?

Comment: Thanks for the replies everyone. Authentication.ClientSesstionTimeout is set to 60. Authentication.ClientPersistentLoginDuration is set to 180. We're going to push it to 240 to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: We have enough account licenses, but will sometimes reach a maximum for reasons we haven't pin-pointed yet. If we reach the maximum, the person logging in will get the option to kick someone, and usually there's some one logged in multiple times. The person with multiple account logins never made those logins - it was done by Sitecore without their knowledge that it even happened.

Comment: This reminded me of another weird bug that we've experienced before this logout issue appeared. Maybe it's relevant? We noticed that the version history (home nodes, pages, etc.) will get overwritten by the system after a restart or something. All versions will have the same time stamp and someone's account name as the person who overwrote it. It's like the system logs in with someone's account and makes changes. If this isn't relevant please ignore as it's another rabbit hole entirely, and not critical.